# How to propertly change time horizon in Avellaneda-Stoikov model?

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies, high-frequency, algorithmic-trading, market-making

I'm working in the Avellaneda-Stoikov implementation using Python. My [implementation](https://github.com/fedecaccia/avellaneda-stoikov) reproduces the authors' results, but I don't know how to properly adapt the algorithm in order to consider a larger time horizon. 
From the equation

```
r = s - q * gamma * sigma**2 * (T-t)
```

if we use larger T, the indifference price computed could become too big compared with the mid price s, or even a negative value, when q is positive.

Is there an a-dimensional implementation? How to independize from T? Is there a possibility to independize also from the election of s?

Answer (score 3):

In [Dealing with the inventory risk: a solution to the market making problem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11579-012-0087-0) (preprint available at [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3115)) we extend the approximation proposed by Marco and Sasha to a rigorous mathematical framework and provide exact steady-state approximation. The bid-ask spread that should be quoted is

$$\psi(q;k,\gamma):=-\frac{1}{k}\ln\frac{f^0_{q-1}f^0_{q+1}}{(f^0_{q})^2}+\frac{2}{\gamma}\ln\frac{\gamma+k}{k},$$
where $k$ is a characteristic of the liquidity consuming flow, $\gamma$ is the MM risk aversion, and the $f^0_q$ are solution of the steady-state version of the ODE driving the value of accepting an inventory of $q$.

The paper explain all this and has been followed by some others. I especially recommend the ones driven by the two other authors:

- Joaquin Fernandez-Tapia went towards **ergodic versions** of the problem during his PhD thesis (identifying [connections with reinforcement learning](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2594477)), and later to versions for **online bets** (especially for internet ad banners)
- Olivier Guéant went to more formal versions of the problem, and later to **reinforcement learning** to [numerically solve multi-dimensional versions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13205)

Comment: Thanks for your response @lehalle, since I lack quant background it was difficult to me to understand the paper you refer, but I will give it another try, trying to focus on the topics you mention. Thanks!